# SQLite3: Delete all rows that share column value and have one or more empty values in another column

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a sqlite3 table with historical stock prices for different companies. The first column is a date, the second is the ticker symbol for the company, and the third column is the stock price for that company at that date. Some stock prices are missing and I would like to delete all the companies that have one or more missing prices. For the company below (ANTQ) I would like to delete all of its rows since there are missing prices. The entire table is very long and has many companies; I do not want to delete those rows for companies that have all the prices non-empty.

```
 date,ticker,price
 19900131,ANTQ,0.125
 19900228,ANTQ,
 19900630,ANTQ,0.094
 19900731,ANTQ,
 19900831,ANTQ,0.094
 19900930,ANTQ,
 19910131,ANTQ,0.094
 19910228,ANTQ,0.094
 19910331,ANTQ,0.094
```

I know how to delete all rows that have an empty price but I do not know how to delete all the rows belonging to a company if one or more of its prices are blank
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to determine the victim companies first:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ticker IN (SELECT ticker
                 FROM MyTable
                 WHERE price IS NULL)
```